# Understanding constructors and final

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does this work:

```
class Person extends StatelessWidget { 
  final String name;

  Person({ this.name });

  ...
}
```

but the following gives an error (`'_name' can't be used as a setter because it is final.
Try finding a different setter, or making name' non-final.`):

```
class Person extends StatelessWidget { 
  final String _name;

  Person({ name }) {
    this._name = name;
  }

  ...
}
```

Is this: `({ this.name })` doing something different under the hood?

Comment: I am aware that the two questions are not completely identical, but I have answered your question in the linked answer and you can even learn about what the initializer list is.